# GORM Recursive Preloading

Tags: go, go-gorm

Using Go 1.10, and CockroachDB via the Postgres `pq` driver.

I have a GORM model that looks like this:

```
type User struct {
    ID            string       `gorm:"type:UUID;primary_key;NOT_NULL"`
    UserName      string
    ... <other misc things here>
    EnclosedUsers []User    `gorm:"many2many:enclosed_user;jointable_foreignkey:parent_id;association_jointable_foreignkey:child_id"`
}
```

where `ecnlosed_user` is (specifically defined because reasons :) )

```
type EnclosedUsers struct {
    ParentID string `gorm:"type:UUID;default:'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"`
    ChildID  string `gorm:"type:UUID;default:'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"`
}
```

That is, each user can have 0 or many enclosed users, and each user may have many parent users. Im trying to `preload` all of the enclosed users for each user, however GORM only preloads the first level.

i.e.:

```
usr1
   |-> usr 2
   |     |->usr3
   |
   |-> usr4
         |->usr6

 usr5
   |->usr7
```

The only users that are loaded are usr1, usr2, usr4, usr5, and usr7. usr3 or usr 6 aren't. Im currently trying to recursively force the enclosed users to load with an `AfterFind` callback:

```
func (u *User) AfterFind(scope *gorm.Scope, role *CRRole) error {
    var childUsers []User

    if err := scope.DB().Model(&u).Related(&childUsers, "EnclosedUsers").Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    role.EnclosedRoles = childRoles

    return nil
}
```

However this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "enclosed_users" ON "enclosed_users"."child_id" = "enclosed_users"."id" WHERE (user_name = 'test user 1') AND ("enclosed_users"."parent_id" IN ('<UUID HERE>'))
```

if the `user_name = ...` wasn't there, the query would work perfectly.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up forking the repository and removing `callback_query_preload.go` at [line 331](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/82eb9f8a5bbb5e6b929d2f0ae5b934e6a253f94e/callback_query_preload.go#L331). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4027 and worked for me perfect.

copy paste from example:

```
type Menu struct{
   Id          int       `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;type:int"`
   Pid         int       `json:"pid" gorm:"primaryKey;type:int"`
   Children    []Menu  `json:"children" gorm:"foreignKey:pid"`
}
func  GetMenusTree() ([]Menu, error) {
    var views []Menu
    err := db.Model(&Menu{}).Where("pid = ?", 0).Preload(clause.Associations, preload).Find(&views).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return views, nil
}

func preload(d *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return d.Preload("Children", preload)
}
```